# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, firebase-crash-reporting

firebase Crashlytics

IWindowSession.java line 844
android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.6'
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1957)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
       at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:844)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:802)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3912)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:183)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

no idea how and where to fix

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to update all your firebase dependency to the latest version or same version in the .gridle file.